# Tmux command to move cursor right/left by one word

Tags: tmux

Outside of tmux, in my terminal (termite), hitting `ctrl-right` or `ctrl-left` will move the cursor right/left by one word. Inside of tmux, hitting those bindings only moves the cursor by one character. I am trying to create a workaround for this. I have not found a tmux command to move the cursor outside of copy mode. This is what I have come up with:

```
 bind -n C-Right copy-mode; send "f q"
```

This enters `copy-mode` and sends the `f` command, which will move the cursor to the next . Then `q` is sent to exit copy mode. The problem with this is that when you leave `copy-mode`, the cursor is put back where it was before entering `copy-mode`.

Am I on the right track? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Settings `set -g xterm-keys on` will allow this in termite.